# Perl Script Explanation

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $args;
$args=@ARGV;

if ($args<1)
{
    die("Expecting a filename");
}
sub showstat
{

    print " $_[0] dev, device number of filesystem\n";
      print " $_[1] ino,      inode number\n";
      print " $_[2] mode,     file mode  (type and permissions)\n";
      print " $_[3] nlink,    number of (hard) links to the file\n";
}

my $filename=$ARGV[0];
if (open (TESTFILE,$filename))
{
    my @filedata= stat(TESTFILE);

    &showstat(@filedata);
    close (TESTFILE);
}
else
{
    print "error on open $filename";

}
```

My question is if we set a variable (`$args`) for the array (`@ARGV`), when we print the line under the sub showstat, shouldn't it be `print"$args[0] ..." print "$args[1]"`?
And for `$filename=$ARGV[0]`, shouldn't it be `$filename=$args[1]`?

And under if statement condition, where it says `&showstat(filedata)`, what does `&` mean? when I've looked it up, it meant "part of", but I am confused with this line that is written.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is if we set a variable (`$args`) for the array (`@ARGV`),
>   when we print the line under the sub `showstat`, shouldn't it be
>   `print"$args[0] ..." print "$args[1]"`?

It shouldn't and must not be `$args[0]` because the parameters passed to subroutine in Perl are stored in `@_` array. If you want to get value of 1st parameter, you must use **$_[0]**

> and for `$filename=$ARGV[0]`, shouldn't it be `$filename=$args[1]`?

What is `$filename`? If it is name of script, you must use **$0** instead of `$ARGV[0]`. `$ARGV[0]` is the first parameter passed to the script.

> and under if statement condition, where it says `&showstat(filedata)`,
>   what does `&` mean?

It just means "Call subroutine `showstat`".

Comment: then why did we set this up?                                     $args;
$args=@ARGV;